# HTML 5 Geolocation is not working

Tags: html, geolocation

ALL HTML 5 geolocation script is not working.And this sample geolocation site
http://www.browsergeolocation.com/ is not working also.Whast could be the reasons why it won't work?

Comment: What is your browser? It work with Firefox 3.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

likely that the browser you are using is not in this list:

http://www.browsergeolocation.com/#browser-gelocation-support

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with Google Chrome 9.0+ beta, Firefox 3.6.13, but not on IE 8.0.7600. However, that makes sense since IE 9.0 is needed for it.  So, it could be like jpstrikesback said, that you are using a non-compatible browser.

Some browsers request that you give permission for that feature to run on your browser.  Make sure you are allowing it to actually work for you.